# How to fix temperamental sublime snippet?

Tags: sublimetext3

I have a relativley simple custom snippet:

```xml
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[
#### ${1:subtitle}
$2
]]></content>
    <!-- Optional: Set a tabTrigger to define how to trigger the snippet -->
    <tabTrigger>st</tabTrigger>
    <!-- Optional: Set a scope to limit where the snippet will trigger -->
    <!-- <scope>source.python</scope> -->
</snippet>
```

It's working about 25% of the time. Sometimes the snippet will work, other times the cursor will randomly jump up about 5 lines, other times it will jump down a couple lines and other times still it will just do a normal tab. Is there any way to fix this so it just works all the time?

Comment: it works fine for me...

Comment: Okay, sot that probably mean it's not the snippet. I took a screencast of the behavior I'm talking about: [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e5jlIkUM5BA&feature=youtu.be) I'm not sure what could be the issue. Could it be that I'm using vintage mode? Are there any config files I should add to my question? Should I uninstall and reinstall?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the was I was using the second tab region with it just being alone as `$2`, a more detailed solution can be found [here](https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/sometimes-snippet-doesnt-work/20132)